# How to find out the table name for a many2many relation (Where is the many2many table name stored?)

Tags: postgresql, orm, xml-rpc, odoo

I am trying to recover data from a broken Odoo installation (uprade got screwed up).

I have exported all the tables to CSV using postgresql (psql). I would also be able to handle many2one and one2many relations.

For many2many relations, I need a way to programatically find out which database table contains the relation details (ids from both the models). I tried to get the data from the ORM "fields_get" function using xmlrpc. The  field definition returns a dictionary which has a key named 'relation'. However this key contains just the name of the other table/ model involved in the relation. For many2many relations there is another 3rd table involved. I am unable to find where odoo stores the name of this table.

Example data:
Let me try to explain my question using an example: In res_partner.py the field category_id is defined as :

```
'category_id': fields.many2many('res.partner.category', id1='partner_id', id2='category_id', string='Tags')`
```

Based on this a new table would be created by Odoo which would hold the many2many relation details. The name of this table is automatically selected by Odoo. I need to know that table name for each many2many field I encounter.

The 'fields_get' function returns the following for this field:

```
'category_id': {'domain': [], 'change_default': False, 'string': 'Tags', 'searchable': True, 'required': False, 'manual': False, 'depends': [], 'readonly': False, 'relation':'res.partner.category', 'context': {}, 'company_dependent': False, 'sortable': True, 'type': 'many2many', 'store': True}
```

The name of the table is not mentioned here. I need that to create a small script to read and export data out of my non-functional odoo instance. When Odoo is running, how does it know which table to read for any many2many relation?

Regards,

Tanveer

Comment: Mr. Pawan on the Odoo forum has mentioned the 'ir_model_relation' table. It provides the names of the many2many tables created by Odoo. However it only provides the module and model id references. When one model has more than one many2many fields, how to identity which row in the table 'ir_model_relation' refers to which field of the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access to module code, the third object is defined from field description:

```
'my_field_ids': fields.many2many('the_other_object', 'relation_object', 'first_id', 'second_id', string='Field Name')
```

So you need to look for ***relation_object*** table.

**Edit:**

You can also check ***ir.model.relation*** table. It contains all information about many2many relations in all modules. you can try something like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"call","params":{"model":"ir.model.relation","domain":[["model","=","my_model"]]}}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. As I mentioned I am trying to recover data from an existing (broken) installation of odoo. It would not be practical to parse the actual module source code programatically and look for the relation_object.

Comment: What do you mean by 'parsing code programmatically' ? If you are looking for the name of the relation table the only way I know is to check code description or to try to get access to postgres database and look for a table with semantic name. Otherwise, I don't think the name of the relation is stored somewhere (except in python code).

Comment: My Question is that once a module is installed, the field definition would be stored somewhere in the database for odoo to read and use later. Where is this stored. I have read the field definition using the ORM function 'fields_get'. However this also does not have the relation_object details.

Comment: OK, that will be helpful. Please do it by editing your question.

Comment: Edited by question and added an example to further clarify what I am asking. Please help.

Comment: I just discovered that there is a table where odoo stores all relational tables description, please check **ir.model.relation** table, it contains all names as you need.

Comment: Thanks again. I also found the same thing a few minutes back. However the problem still remain. The table ir.model.relation does not mention which row of the table is for which field of the model. It only mentions the model id. In the example that I mentioned above, the table ir.model.relation has 7-8 rows having the name "res_partner_res_partner_category_rel" and model id = 64 (which is res_partner in my case). Additionally there is another row with name ""crm_meeting_partner_rel". This refers to another many2many field in the same model. How to find out which row refers to which field?

Comment: Normally, *ir.model.relation* table save the relation name given when describing the many2many field (the name of the field is not stored). If the relation name not given, so the name will be like this *model1_model2_rel*. If you defined two fields related to the same model, you should then give different name, if not it will be a confusion, so both relation will be stored in the same table. **Resume**: The field is defined by three information: module, model, and the relation name (given by developer or automatically mod1_mod2_rel). In case of confusion, different names must be given.

Answer (score 0):

i want to explain how odoo framework create related table for many2many 
for exemple we have your `model1` where you created "category_id" and the other `model2` where you Create the relation with many2many

Now 
for each models odoo create table in Psql , so for  models1 odoo create in Psql `table:model1` and for the second model Psql create `table: Model2` 
and for the relation many2many Psql create the third his name is `table:model1_Model2`

so in odoo create this table with `underscore` and the 2 table Name